# Super Mario Bros. Wonder: Jet Run II is impossible

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

I don't get this level. I've died like 50 times jumping only once. I've looked at walkthrough videos and they all seem to be jumping in the air somehow like they have double jump or something simultaneously enabled with the running shoes. I can't seem to pull one off one of these sky jumps. No threads talking about it. I'm not sure if I'm taking too many crazy pills or not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Jet Run badge equipped you can run off an edge and then do a jump mid-air, if you fail you probably waited for too long and the special effect just timed out.

The first couple of jumps even show you the exact moment you are supposed to jump mid-air, as you can see:

[image]

The "jump window" is essentially the blue part, when the character is still running and can do a mid-air jump. If you pass that window, you won't be able to perform the jump. Jumping too early, by the way, won't let you reach the next platform.

Remember that, in case you jump too early, you can always press <kbd>R</kbd> to do an aerial spin that can give you a little extra momentum that can let you reach the next platform.

Comment: That's no help at all. I already know that much. When is the god damn jump window??

Comment: I've attached an image, if that can help you

Comment: It's worth noting that this effect is *not* a double jump—you need to run off the platform to be able to jump in midair. If you jump off the platform instead, you don't get a second jump.

Comment: @pimanrules - A.k.a highly extended "coyote time"?